# Eclipse Maven project structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am fairly new to maven. In Eclipse, I created a maven project
Inside this I can see src/main/java and src/test/java also there is one more src folder which again contains main and test folder. Here I am confused in which src folder I need to write the code. What is the main benefit of using main and test folder? Why there are two main and two src folder

[image: file]

Comment: src/main/java  at top is package structure and other one is folder structure, its doesnt matter, you create classes in your package and they will be reflected in bottom one just like filesystem. These are not two but one structure only

Comment: And test folder is where you write your test cases for unit testing, only when you do maven test, they will be executed. You main code is is src/main/java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In any application you will have two "kinds" of code:

- Production code
- Test code

Production code is what produces your application. In Maven (and Gradle too) you define a "main" module where your code will be located. So it's located at `src/main`. Inside you may have several folders:

- `src/main/java` for Java code
- `src/main/kotlin` for Kotlin code
- ...

Test code is what assures that your Production code works fine. As Production code it needs to be placed inside a "module" usually called "test". So your test code will be located a `src/test`. And as in Production code you may have several folders:

- `src/test/java` for tests written in Java
- `src/test/kotlin` for tests written in Kotlin
- ...

It's a good practice to test your Production code to ensure that it indeed works as it should. The reality is that it's not strange to find a developer that doesn't write any test because "it's time consuming". But I strongly recommend you to learn how to write quality tests

That's all talking about "development time". At "deploy time" the only code that became an application is the only that is located inside `main` module

Comment: so I have to write to my code inside top src/main/java folder and it will be automatically reflected in below src folder ..correct?

Comment: Yep, you write code in `src/main/java` folder and IDE **should** reflect it in below src folder. Personally I don't like very much Eclipse style of displaying this kind of info. I prefer the IntelliJ IDEA style

Comment: I started writing my code in top src/main/java folder but it is not reflecting inside below src folder @Pelocho

Answer (score 2):

I can see, you are confused with both `src/main` or `src/test` folders.

You should notice that `src/main/java` at the top is how `maven` shows the folders. 
and `src->main->java` (one folder inside another) is how your files actually gets stored in the `workspace on the disk`.

So if you would look at your `workspace` you would find folders like you have at the bottom. One inside another.

Now you ask why there are two copies: First one at the top is where we write the code. In the second `src` (which is actual folders on the disk) at the bottom it gets automatically reflected all the files that you created in the top `src`. So apparently `src` at the top is not actual folders on the disk, it is just how `maven` shows the source folders.

`Main` is where your business logic resides, `Test` is where you place your `testing code` for above logic!

Comment: so I have to write to my code inside top src/main/java folder and it will be automatically reflected in below src folder ..correct?

Comment: yup! @SaurabhGarg

Answer (score 1):

the bottom src folder us where the unit tests should be. Don't worry if you dont know what that means. In the top folder is where the java code should be located.

Comment: Do, I have to maintain my code in two places? one in test and another in main..is it?

Comment: no the unit tests are optional, you don't need to write anything in the test folder.

Comment: @SaurabhGarg If you want to do it WELL, it is just what you must to do - to hold tests in separate folder, but in the same packages that are tested. It is how nowadays tests are organized.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see src/main/test I see src/test in your screenshot.

It's a valid structure of separating tests from real code.

test package will not be deployed to production site. It'll be used only in development/QA/integration environments.

Comment: Do I need to maintain my code in two places? first I need to write in test then in Main..is it?

Comment: No duplication of code. ONLY tests in test folder. and in main folder the real code

Comment: scr/main/java, scr/main/sources, scr/main/scala, scr/test/java, scr/test/sources, scr/test/scala,....

Comment: @SaurabhGarg Not in src/Main nor in main()!

Answer (score 0):

They are one and the same. If you look at the directory using Windows Explorer or via the command line, you will see that there is only one **src/main/java** and one **src/test/java**. The folders you are seeing below are like how you view it in Explorer, as folders and files. The one you are seeing up top is a Java representation of the folders, which are package names. Your production code goes in **main** while your test code goes in **test**. In other words the class under test are located in **main** while the test class is located in **test**.